# Ajax обновление в Loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Функция обновления divов - графиков: 
Удаляем все графики из контейнера,
id параметра и его имя как обьект записывалем в массив,
и для каждого создаем новый график.

Проблема в том, что значения переменным присваиваются правильно в каждой итерации, но все divы имеют id из последней итерации. Я не слышал о том, что ajax не работает в цикле, при этом у всех графиков разные данные.

Проверил в инструментах разработчика, видимо, сначала программа проходит весь цикл, а затем выполняет ajax-запрос, из-за этого id один у всех.

```js
function refreshGraphs(s, e) {

        $('#graphsBlock').html('<div class="vertical" id="vertical">');
        var PointId;
        var PointName;
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)
        {
            var dateS = dateStart.GetDate();
            var dateF = dateFinish.GetDate();
            PointId = selection[i].id;
            PointName = selection[i].name;
            var _dateS = dateS.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
            var _dateF = dateF.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
            var _focusID = PointId.substring(0, PointId.length - 1);
            alert(PointId + ' ' + PointName);

            (function (i) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/Monitoring/Monitoring/MonitorGraph',
                    data: {
                        param: _focusID,
                        start: _dateS,
                        finish: _dateF,
                        id: PointId,
                        grName: PointName
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (Serverdata) {
                        $("#graphsBlock").append('<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5%; width: 90%;" id="' + PointId + '">' + Serverdata + '</div>');
                    }
                });
            })(i);
        }      
    }
```

Comment: а зачем замыкать `i`, есть внутри коллбэка используются `PointId` и `PointName`?

Comment: Это на данный момент последняя версия функции, добавил замыкание из топика на форуме, без него ситуация та же (использовал x = $.ajax ({...});

Comment: Перечитай мой комментарий: _а **зачем замыкать i**, если внутри коллбэка используются **PointId** и **PointName**?_ Обрати внимание на выделенные участки

Comment: т.к. PointId и PointName зависят от i. они различны на каждой итерации

Comment: ок, **покажи** где ты _внутри замыкания_ используешь `i`

Comment: не использую, но немного от сути вопроса отошли, как тогда сделать, чтобы ajax-запрос выполнялся отдельно на каждой итерации?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62583/discussion-between-grundy-and-maxkb24).